__dirname give the wrong path
Trying to use __dirname in webpack, the project path is like /home/myname/workplace/projectname
but
console.log(`__dirname: ${__dirname}`);

returned:
__dirname: /local/home/myname/workplace/projectname

Why is the __dirname prefixed with /local?
NodeJS version: v18.20.2
I want to know the root cause and get a solution for fix.

Where in webpack?

can you provide the result of command ls -l /home
